# No plugin exists with the handle "contact-form-extensions"

Tags: plugins

I have installed and used the Contact Form Extensions plugin a few times but this time it's not working. I can see it in the CP but when I click to install it throws the error:

> Invalid plugin – craft\errors\InvalidPluginException
>   'No plugin exists with the handle "contact-form-extensions".'

When I install it the command line does say something about Carbon 1 being deprecated but not sure if it's related?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running `./craft project-config/rebuild` from your terminal.

Comment: Yes that fixed it! No idea why - thanks Oli

Comment: Oli for some reason doing that seems to have massively sped up how fast my local version loads both in CP and website - not sure why but thanks!

Comment: We all love of bit of speed ;)

Comment: fantastic... saved the day (or a few hours at least). can you also give an explanation why this is happening?